# Issue with Mobile Accordion in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin that displays a table of distributors on the desktop view and an accordion on mobile devices to show the details of each distributor. However, I'm encountering an issue with the mobile accordion, as the details are not being displayed when clicking on the distributor's name.

I have reviewed my PHP and JavaScript code multiple times, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the problem. In the browser console, I see that `console.log(nombreCell)` displays "null," and `console.log(detalleCells)` displays "[]." This indicates that the selectors are not finding the desired elements in the DOM.

Here is a portion of my JavaScript code that handles the accordion:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        if (window.innerWidth > 600) return; // No ejecutar en pantallas más grandes.
        var distribuidorRows = document.querySelectorAll(".distribuidores-table tbody tr");
        
        distribuidorRows.forEach(function(row) {
            var nombreCell = row.querySelector("td[data-label=\'Nombre\']");
            var detalleCells = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll("td:not(:first-child)"));

           
        console.log(nombreCell); // Verifica si se selecciona la celda del nombre
        console.log(detalleCells); // Verifica si se seleccionan las celdas de detalle

            detalleCells.forEach(function(cell) {
                cell.style.display = "none"; // Esconder los detalles inicialmente.
            });
            
            nombreCell.addEventListener("click", function() {
                detalleCells.forEach(function(cell) {
                    cell.style.display = cell.style.display === "none" ? "table-cell" : "none";
                });
            });
        });
    });

nombreCell.addEventListener("click", function() {
    detalleCells.forEach(function(cell) {
        cell.style.display = cell.style.display === "none" ? "table-cell" : "none";
    });
});
```

Here I have the PHP code that create the table:

```
$buscar_nombre = isset($_GET['buscar_nombre']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['buscar_nombre']) : '';
    $filtro_provincia = isset($_GET['filtro_provincia']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['filtro_provincia']) : '';
    $filtro_pais = isset($_GET['filtro_pais']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['filtro_pais']) : '';
    
    $distribuidores = $this->obtenerDistribuidoresFiltrados($buscar_nombre, $filtro_provincia, $filtro_pais);
    
    if (!empty($distribuidores)) {
        echo '<table class="distribuidores-table">';
        echo '<tr class="encabezados"><th class="header-cell">Nombre</th><th class="header-cell">Dirección</th><th class="header-cell">Teléfono</th><th class="header-cell">Provincia</th><th class="header-cell">País</th></tr>';
        foreach ($distribuidores as $distribuidor) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td data-label="Nombre"><strong>' . esc_html($distribuidor->nombre) . '</strong></td>';
            echo '<td data-label="Dirección">' . esc_html($distribuidor->direccion) . '</td>';
            echo '<td data-label="Teléfono">' . esc_html($distribuidor->telefono) . '</td>';
            echo '<td data-label="Provincia">' . esc_html($distribuidor->provincia) . '</td>';
            echo '<td data-label="País">' . esc_html($distribuidor->pais) . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'No se encontraron distribuidores.';
    }
```

I think the problem is the selectors.